# vhdl DFF assert statments

Tags: vhdl, assert

**Description:**
I want to include vhdl assert statements to report when set_delay and hold_delay time violations occur. I am not sure how to do this with my code and I have been to many places on the web and I don't understand. Please give examples with my code.

**Code:**

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY dff IS 
GENERIC (set_delay : TIME := 3 NS; prop_delay : TIME := 12 NS; 
        hold_delay : TIME := 5 NS);
PORT (d, set, rst, clk : IN BIT; q : OUT BIT; nq : OUT BIT := '1');
END dff;
--
ARCHITECTURE dff OF dff IS
SIGNAL state : BIT := '0';
BEGIN
 dff: PROCESS
BEGIN
  wait until rst;
  wait until set;
  wait until clk;

IF set = '1' THEN
  q <= '1' AFTER set_delay;
  nq <= '0' AFTER set_delay;
ELSIF rst = '1' THEN
  q <= '0' AFTER prop_delay;
  nq <= '1' AFTER prop_delay;
ELSIF clk = '1' AND clk'EVENT THEN
  q <= d AFTER hold_delay; 
  nq <= NOT d AFTER hold_delay;
END IF;
END PROCESS dff;
END dff;
```

I do understand that the general assert syntax is:

```
ASSERT
condition
REPORT
"message"
SEVERITY
severity level;
```

Part of my problem is that I don't know where to put these assert statements and I am not sure how I would write them.

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce additional signals in which you store the time of the last manipulation. Then I'd add other process which manage the signals and check the times:.

```
time_debug : block
signal t_setup, t_hold : time := 0 ns;
begin

setup_check : process (clk)
begin
if clk'event and clk = '1' then
  t_hold <= now;
  assert (t_setup - now)>set_delay REPORT "Setup time violated." SEVERITY note;
end if;
end process setup_check;

hold_check: process (d)
begin 
if d'event then
  t_setup <= now;  
  assert (t_hold - now)>hold_delay REPORT "Hold time violated." SEVERITY note;
end if; 
end process hold_check;
end block time_debug;
```

What this does is it saves the time of the last positive clock edge and the time of the last input change. Now every time either d changes or the clock rises the delays are checked. I couldn't verify this in a compiler because I don't have one set up here, but I'll gladly do so if there are problems with this solution.

I personally like to keep debug stuff in a dedicated block, so I can easily keep track of which signals I only use for debugging and can later easily remove them. It also makes it easier to add all debug signals to e.g. modelsim's wave screen.

Also note that these asserts and reports will only work in simulation.